# is function convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose that $a_i$ has a normal distribution with mean $E(a_i)$ and variance $var(a_i)$ ,  we have for  $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i $ ,

$$E (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(a_i) x_i,$$

and

$$var (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n var(a_i) x_i ^2 +2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} cov(a_i,a_j)x_ix_j,$$

where $cov(a_i,a_j)x_ix_j$  is a covariance. Is this function convex ?

$$\sqrt{ \sum_i x_i ^2 var(a_i)+ 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n}cov(a_i,a_j)x_ix_j  +  \sum_{i=1}^n E(a_i) x_i } $$

Comment: What is 'this function' that your question refers to?

Comment: @LinAlg Hi :-)  in stochastic programing with  chance constraint , this function appeared in constrain

Comment: You mean the expression with the square root? So if $f(x) = \sqrt{x^T A x + b^T x}$ is convex when $A$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: @ LinAlg hi , yes  the expression with the square root , and  here $  A=var +cov$ ? i know $cov$ matrix is positive definite . what is  A in this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $a_1\sim \mathcal{N}(-1,1)$ then
$$
\Delta = \sqrt{ var(a_1) x_1^2 + E(a_1) x_1}=\sqrt{x_1^2-x_1}
$$
is not defined over a cone. Further, if $a_1\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$
$$
\Delta = \sqrt{ var(a_1) x_1^2 + E(a_1) x_1} = |x_1|.
$$

Comment: hello,  I have n parameters, and suppose in spesial case , we have $a_1,...,a_n ~N(0,1)$ , is$ \Delta =|x_1+...x_n|$ ?

Comment: No, let $a_1, a_2\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. First, if $a_1, a_2$ are independent then $ cov(a_1,a_2)=0 $ and $$ \Delta = \sqrt{|x_1^2+x_2^2|}.$$ Second, if $a_1, a_2$ are  correlated with $cov(a_1,a_2)=1$ then $$  \Delta =|x_1+x_2|.$$

Comment: Yes ,thanks a lot